# сложение двух списков python

Tags: python, списки

у меня есть два списка

```
BOT_HELLO = ('привет', 'прив', 'дарова')
BOT_NAMES = ('Джаред', 'Джар', 'бот')
```

и мне нужно на выходе получить третий список такого типа

```
THIRD = ('привет Джаред', 'привет Джар', 'привет бот', 'прив Джаред', 'прив Джар', 'прив бот', 'дарова Джаред', 'дарова Джар', 'дарова бот')
```

подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

res = [f'{x} {y}' for x,y in product(BOT_HELLO, BOT_NAMES)]

print(res)
```

результат:

```
['привет Джаред', 'привет Джар', 'привет бот', 'прив Джаред', 'прив Джар', 'прив бот', 'дарова Джаред', 'дарова Джар', 'дарова бот']
```

Comment: ну вот, а как же numpy?
там же вроде быстрее?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, при работе со строками бывает что решение с использованием Numpy проигрывает по скорости ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
[ i+" "+j for i in BOT_HELLO for j in BOT_NAMES ]

['привет Джаред', 'привет Джар', 'привет бот', 'прив Джаред', 'прив Джар', 'прив бот', 'дарова Джаред', 'дарова Джар', 'дарова бот']
```